# integer argument expected error tkinter python 3.4

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I'm currently trying to help a friend out with the same task that i have previously done, but im stuck. once the program is run and 'get tickets' is pressed this error message is displayed:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1533, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\harding\Documents\Oli\Homework\Year10\Computing\New folder\carpark 3.4 (1).py", line 21, in reg_output
    b.readlines(v.get())
TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str'

code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import time

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Car Park')

    v = StringVar()

   car_in=Label(root, text= "Please enter your reg number")
   car_in.grid(column=1, row=1)

   reg_input=Entry(root, textvariable =v)
   reg_input.grid(column=1, row=2)

   def reg_input():
     with open ('tickets.txt', 'w') as b:
        b.writelines(v.get())

   def reg_output():
     with open ('tickets.txt', 'r') as b:
        b.readlines(v.get())

   reg_input_but=Button(root, text='Submit', command=reg_input)
   reg_input_but.grid(column=1, row=4)

   reg_output_b=Button(root, text='Get Ticket', command=reg_output)
   reg_output_b.grid(column=1, row=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

v is a Stringvar, therefore v.get() returns a string. b.readlines(lines) requires lines to be an integer because lines determines how many lines are supposed to be read. If you omit the argument it will read all lines.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, function `readlines` expects integer arguments and `v.get()` returns a string, causing the error. What you can do is simply change `b.readlines(v.get())` on line 21 to `b.readlines()` to fix the error.

Here's the edited code.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('Car Park')

v = StringVar()

car_in=Label(root, text= "Please enter your reg number")
car_in.grid(column=1, row=1)

reg_input=Entry(root, textvariable =v)
reg_input.grid(column=1, row=2)

def reg_input():
    with open ('tickets.txt', 'w') as b:
        b.writelines(v.get())

def reg_output():
    with open ('tickets.txt', 'r') as b:
        b.readlines()

reg_input_but=Button(root, text='Submit', command=reg_input)
reg_input_but.grid(column=1, row=4)

reg_output_b=Button(root, text='Get Ticket', command=reg_output)
reg_output_b.grid(column=1, row=5)
```